# code translation form c# to c++

Tags: .net, visual-c++

what is the equivalent in vc++ ?

```
    int i = 0;

    private TabPage[] tab = new TabPage[20];

    i++;

    tab[i] = new TabPage();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent in VC++. TabPage is GUI control; you can create something similar in C++ using Win API or maybe MFC, even Qt if you prefer it. If you want something equivalent in C++/CLI (.NET Framework again) you can create an array of TabPages:

```
array<TabPage^> ^ tabPage = gcnew array<TabPage^>(20);
```

Comment: Hey using this I have ; only static data members can be initialized in a class of reference or a value type

Comment: OK, then declare it in a class body, and define it in a constructor.
For example:
array<TabPage^> ^ tabPage;   //   In a class body
...
tabPage = gcnew array<TabPage^>(20); // In a constructor

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what are you doing with private there.

```
int i = 0;

TabPage * tab[20];

i++;

tab[i] = new TabPage();
```

EDIT: Oh, yes, I have no idea what TabPAge is; if you are actually trying to do some specific GUI task this won't help you much.